# What is the type of lever when we stand on tiptoes?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

In my textbook it's written that the fulcrum will be the toes, the force will be the muscles (gastrocnemius) in the lower leg, and the load will be around the heel area. Thus it will be 2nd class lever. I understand the force and fulcrum, but shouldn't load be at the center of mass of the person? Why is it at the heel?